# How to draw a circle intersecting a shaded non-uniform shape using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this picture:

[image: circle intersecting a shaded non-uniform shape]

I have tried a lot of things, like defining this

```
\newcommand\irregularcircle[2]{
    \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
    +(0:\len pt)
    \foreach \a in {10,20,...,120}{
        \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
        -- +(\a:\len pt)
    } -- cycle
}
```

But it don't give a figure that can be between the x-axis and the circle, and I don't know how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Try http://www.tikzedt.org/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One possibility is tp build up a random list and plots a smooth curve through it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetseed{9}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,11}
 {\ifnum\X=0
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{2}
   \xdef\myLst{\myradius}
  \else
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{{\myLst}[\X-1]+0.5*(rnd-0.5)}
   \xdef\myLst{\myLst,\myradius}
  \fi}
 \xdef\myLst{\myLst,2} 
 \draw[pattern=north east lines] (2,0) -- 
 plot[smooth,variable=\x,samples at={0,...,12}] 
  ([xshift=2cm]-\x*10:{{\myLst}[\x]}) -- (-60:2) arc(-60:0:2);
 \draw (120:2) arc (120:-120:2);
 \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (5,0);
 \draw[dashed] (2,0) -- (2,-pi);
 \draw (2,0) -- ++ (-120:pi);
 \draw[latex-latex] (2,0) + (-120:2.7) arc(-120:-90:2.7) node[midway,below]{$\mu$};
 \draw[-latex] (2,0) -- ++ (-45:1) node[pos=1.2]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marmot, you are a tikz god. Its the 4th question that you answer to me. Thanks a lot. I will put you in my acknowledgments of the tesis.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez It's my pleasure and no need to put acknowledgments.

Comment: @marmot should be in a lot of thesis.

Comment: @marmot Miss \mathcal{U}_1? :-)

Comment: @marmot is it happen anything with me?

Comment: @Sebastiano I do not understand the comment. But please do not expect me to update my answer to add a U, there are several other things in the screen shot which I did not put in but the OP seems to be happy with it. This answer is only on the circle with some noise added on the radius.

Comment: @marmot You misunderstood me this time, there's a smile. I just meant that you did everything perfect and left out one unnecessary detail.